# How to convert typescript number to Hex?

Tags: typescript1.8

I have googled for the past hour and can't find anything on typescript conversion of number to hex.  The javascript solutions don't work.

How can I turn 100 into its hex representation using typescript?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`toString(16)` is what you're looking for.

```
var g: number = 255;
alert(g.toString(16));
```

Comment: It was my fault.  I'm switching between c# and typescript all the time and wrote c# code for typescript.  Thanks..

Comment: This isn't working, it fails on the build. Getting the error: "error TS2554: Expected 0 arguments, but got 1."

Comment: @Jeremy, it sounds like your variable is a string rather than a number. Number definitely has this method.

Answer (score 5):

As found on http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/5089e0/number-object-method-in-typescript-part-41/

```
number.toString(16);
```